# Chains in definable groups

Tags: model-theory

Let $L$ be a countable language and let $T$ be a complete $\omega$-stable $L$ theory (with infinite models). Assume that $T$ contains a definable group (for ease we may as well assume that $x=x$ is a definable group). It is known that there is no infinite descending chain of definable subgroups.

Is it possible to have a infinite chain of descending subgroups that are necessarily not definable? If so are there sufficient/ necessary conditions for such an occurrence? i.e. the chain is definable in stronger logics $L_{\infty\omega}$ etc?

Edit 1: Taking in to account to the comments I have changed it to $\omega$-stable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - isn't $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ a stable group and $G_i=2^i\mathbb{Z}$ a descending sequence of subgroups?

Comment: Noah is right. You need to assume $\omega$-stability or restrict to uniformly definable chains of subgroups (in which context the question doesn't make sense).

Comment: And $\omega$-stable groups typically *will* have infinite descending chains of (non-definable) subgroups. Think about an infinite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thank you for your comments. Alex, if you want to expand you comment to an answer (even if only for the first part) and outline why the second part doesn't make sense, that would be really helpful.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @dav11 OK, I wrote an answer. Would you like me to add anything? Regarding "doesn't make sense", all I meant is that in the superstable non-$\omega$-stable context there are no *uniformly* definable descending chains of subgroups, and it doesn't make sense to ask about not necessarily definable chains, because already there are non-uniformly definable chains.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Nope. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski models, you can easily prove that *any* theory with infinite models has a model with an infinite descending chain of elementary submodels. So there's no hope of proving the descending chain condition for arbitrary subgroups in any model-theoretic context.

You might ask, given an $\omega$-stable theory $T$ extending the theory of groups, which models of $T$ have infinite descending chains of subgroups. The answer should be "most of them"... Since $\omega$-stable theories have prime models over sets, it's even really easy to get infinite descending chains of elementary submodels. To avoid this, you at least need to assume that every strongly minimal set in the model has finite dimension and there are only finitely many strongly minimal sets up to non-orthogonality.